# function from_dict() failing for unknown reason in python

Tags: python, json, python-dataclasses

I converted below JSON using https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-python   to a dataclass:

```
{
"bypassCd": [
            "Duis sint ipsum in",
            "consequat"
          ] 
}
```

It generaged below dataclass - for some reason, it is showing error at  .from_dict()  method and I'm unable to figure it out. Please advise

```
from typing import List
from typing import Any
from dataclasses import dataclass
import json

@dataclass
class Root:
    bypassCd: List[str]

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'Root':
        _bypassCd = [.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("bypassCd")]
        return Root(_bypassCd)


# Example Usage
jsonstring = json.loads(''' 
{
        "bypassCd": [
            "Duis sint ipsum in",
            "consequat"
        ] }
''')

root = Root.from_dict(jsonstring)
print(root)
```

error:

```
 File "/local_home/afxx1285/pyprograms/test2.py", line 11
    _bypassCd = [.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("bypassCd")]
                 ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `.from_dict(y)` is definitely a syntax error.  You need something like `some_object.from_dict(y)` or `from_dict(y)`

Comment: Also, telling "there's an error", but not giving the error message doesn't really help.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski  does that mean the dataclass generator is wrong?  thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @liberforce  added  error as well.  thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Why are you calling `from_dict` inside `from_dict` are you trying to get some recursion? Can the `byPassCd` property contain other serialized `Root` objects?

Comment: Nevermind, I missed the part where you were saying it's generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with, but it's hard to say if it fits your needs. I can't understand why it's trying some recursion calling `from_dict` from inside `from_dict`.

```
from typing import Mapping, List
from dataclasses import dataclass
import json

@dataclass
class Root:
    bypassCd: List[str]

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Mapping) -> 'Root':
        _bypassCd = obj.get("bypassCd", [])
        return Root(_bypassCd)


# Example Usage
my_dict = json.loads('''
{
    "bypassCd": [
        "Duis sint ipsum in",
        "consequat"
    ]
}
''')

root = Root.from_dict(my_dict)
print(root)
```

Comment: BTW, this generator sucks if it can't generate at least syntactically correct code for such a simple example...

Comment: The explanations on the generator page (at the bottom) make sense, but even that sucks as they are not keeping the indentation that is Python requires. That site is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `SyntaxError` on this line:

```py
_bypassCd = [.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("bypassCd")]
```

... because you are trying to run the method/function `from_dict`, but you haven't written which object holds this function. You could specify an object like this before the function call:

```py
obj.from_dict(y)
```

I think what you want to do is recursively call the `Root.from_dict` function, so you should probably write:

```py
Root.from_dict(y)
```

This still throws an error since your algorithm needs some changes, but this answers your initial question.

Comment: thanks for taking a look -  Root.from_dict(y)   doesnt seem working..

Comment: You're right, I answered your first question regarding why you were getting the first error. If you need more help, it might be best to move it to a new question. StackOverflow is not a code writing platform, if you need help with a specific bug then search for it first, then ask here.